# Can I avoid having to delete ".gradle" folder in root project every time I run my project?

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-emulator

I have been getting this issue from a while.

```
error processing /home/sajid/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/6.0/bc6fa6b19424bb9592fe43bbc20178f92d403105/asm-6.0.jar
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:142)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyzeJar(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:92)
    at com.android.builder.desugaring.DesugaringClassAnalyzer.analyze(DesugaringClassAnalyzer.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.lambda$getInitalGraphData$4(DesugarIncrementalTransformHelper.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
:app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I have found that one solution is to delete `.gradle` folder from the root of the project and then run again.  It works, but I would prefer not to have to do this.

Please review the logs (above) and suggest a better solution to what I am currently forced to do.

Current version:

> ```
> compileSdkVersion 27
>
> buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
>
> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
>
> Android Studio 3.
> ```

Comment: can you show the Screen shot where are you deleting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to delete gradle every time here is the steps you can try:
 - Go to file
 - click invalidate cache and restart.
Might be it will help